# NOW() can't be used in query (it doesn't exist)

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

In my Go code, I have this line of code:

```
rows, err := conn.Query(`
    SELECT id, name, lang, deleted_at, read
    FROM categories
    WHERE deleted_at < NOW()
`)
```

When I run this, I get an error from PostgreSQL:

```
pq: function  now() does not exist
```

(pq is the Go driver that I use)

Using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` also provokes an error. It says that the column `current_timestamp` does not exist. Using `NOW()` directly in `psql` (command line) does not provoke that error and everything works fine.

Any idea on why I can't use `NOW()` nor `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` when sending a query from my Go app?

Comment: whats the exact code that failed with current_timestamp?

Comment: Same code. Just change `NOW()` for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. I get `pq: column " current_timestamp" does not exist`.

Comment: Did you surround current_timestamp with double-quotes? That's the only way I can think of to get that error.

Comment: No I didn't and the queries work in `psql`.

Comment: The two spaces between `function` and `now()` in the error message are suspicious, there should only be one space. Are you certain that nothing is modifying your query before it gets to PostgreSQL? Can you get a look at the SQL that is sent to PostgreSQL rather than the SQL in your Go code? If I say `select " f"();` then I get two spaces (but no quotes) in the error message, if I say `select f();` then I only get one space.

Comment: Try swapping the code to read `WHERE NOW() > deleted_at` to see what that gives as the error.

Comment: Swapped: `pq: syntax error at or near "AND NOW"`. I'm trying to find a way to see the formatted query.

Comment: Where did the `AND` come from?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I was trying other queries.

Comment: Tried. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My right alt key on my keyboard got stuck without me noticing. That made me insert non-breakable spaces when pressing the space bar. PostgreSQL probably interpreted the non-breakable space as a character that is part of the function's name.

Inserting regular spaces instead solved the issue.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue (though I expect my non-breaking spaces to originate elsewhere, even though I have no idea where), I am surprised how hard to find the issue is and how few people seem to have encountered it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there is nothing wrong with your query.  PostgreSQL can throw function not found at you also when the function actually exists but a different value type is expected.

The function now() returns [timestamp with time zone](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html). If the column deleted_at is not of the same type, you might need to cast either deleted_at or the output from now().